# libvirt-lxc container on Debian buster with user namespacing not always startable

Tags: debian, libvirt, lxc

I have a bunch of libvirt-lxc containers whose configuration I migrated from Debian jessie to a fresh Debian buster host. I re-created the rootfs’ for the containers using `lxc-create -t debian -- --release buster` and later remapped the uid/gid numbers of the rootfs with a script I know to work correctly.

The container configuration looks like this:

```
<domain type='lxc'>
  <name>some-container</name>
  <uuid>1dbc80cf-e287-43cb-97ad-d4bdb662ca43</uuid>
  <title>Some Container</title>
  <memory unit='KiB'>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <memtune>
    <swap_hard_limit unit='KiB'>2306867</swap_hard_limit>
  </memtune>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64'>exe</type>
    <init>/sbin/init</init>
  </os>
  <idmap>
    <uid start='0' target='200000' count='65535'/>
    <gid start='0' target='200000' count='65535'/>
  </idmap>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_lxc</emulator>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <source dir='/var/lib/lxc/some-container/rootfs/'/>
      <target dir='/'/>
    </filesystem>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <source dir='/var/www/some-container/static/'/>
      <target dir='/var/www/some-container/static/'/>
    </filesystem>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:a1:98:03'/>
      <source bridge='guests0'/>
      <ip address='192.0.2.3' family='ipv4' prefix='24'/>
      <ip address='2001:db8::3' family='ipv6' prefix='112'/>
      <route family='ipv4' address='0.0.0.0' prefix='0' gateway='192.0.2.1'/>
      <route family='ipv6' address='2000::' prefix='3' gateway='fe80::1'/>
      <target dev='vcontainer0'/>
      <guest dev='eth0'/>
    </interface>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/21'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/21'/>
      <target type='lxc' port='0'/>
      <alias name='console0'/>
    </console>
    <hostdev mode='capabilities' type='misc'>
      <source>
        <char>/dev/net/tun</char>
      </source>
    </hostdev>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

(IP addresses have been changed to use the documentation/example IPv4/IPv6 prefixes.) The mountpoints exist and are prepared. I have about 15 containers similar to this. The following things happen:

- When the host is freshly booted, I can either:

  - start a container with user namespacing, and then only containers without user namespacing
  - start a container without user namespacing, and then **no** containers with user namespacing

When I run `virsh -c lxc:/// start some-container` after any other container is already started, libvirt claims to have started the container:

```
# virsh -c lxc:/// start some-container
Domain some-container started
```

It also shows as running in the `virsh -c lxc:/// list` output, but there is no process running under the root UID of the container. Running `systemctl restart libvirtd` makes libvirt recognize that the container is actually dead and mark it as `shut off` in `virsh -c lxc:/// list` again.

When looking into the libvirt logs, I can’t find anything useful:

```
2019-05-09 15:38:38.264+0000: starting up
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin LIBVIRT_DEBUG=4 LIBVIRT_LOG_OUTPUTS=4:stderr /usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_lxc --name some-container --console 25 --security=apparmor --handshake 52 --veth vnet0
PATH=/bin:/sbin TERM=linux container=lxc-libvirt HOME=/ container_uuid=1dbc80cf-e287-43cb-97ad-d4bdb662ca43 LIBVIRT_LXC_UUID=1dbc80cf-e287-43cb-97ad-d4bdb662ca43 LIBVIRT_LXC_NAME=some-container /sbin/init
```

(NB: I tried with and without apparmor)

I became quite desperate and attached strace with `strace -ff -o somedir/foo -p` to libvirtd and then started a container. After a lot of digging, I found out that libvirt starts `/sbin/init` inside the container, which then quickly exits with status code 255. This is after an EACCESS upon doing something with cgroups:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/libvirtd.service/init.scope/cgroup.procs", O_WRONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
writev(3, [{iov_base="\33[0;1;31m", iov_len=9}, {iov_base="Failed to create /system.slice/l"..., iov_len=91}, {iov_base="\33[0m", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 4) = 105
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 5, NULL)    = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
writev(3, [{iov_base="\33[0;1;31m", iov_len=9}, {iov_base="Failed to allocate manager objec"..., iov_len=52}, {iov_base="\33[0m", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 4) = 66
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/console", O_WRONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=0, ws_col=0, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
writev(4, [{iov_base="[", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="\33[0;1;31m!!!!!!\33[0m", iov_len=19}, {iov_base="] ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="Failed to allocate manager objec"..., iov_len=34}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 5) = 57
close(4)                                = 0
writev(3, [{iov_base="\33[0;1;31m", iov_len=9}, {iov_base="Exiting PID 1...", iov_len=16}, {iov_base="\33[0m", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 4) = 30
exit_group(255)                         = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

Digging further, I figured that libvirt is not creating a Cgroup namespace for the containers, and apparently they all try to use the same cgroup path. With that, the behaviour makes sense: If the first container which is started is user-namespaced, it takes ownership of the cgroup subtree and other user-namespaced containers cannot use it. The non-user-namespaced containers can simply take over the cgroup tree because they run as UID 0.

The question is now: why are the cgroups configured incorrectly? Is it a libvirt bug? Is it a misconfiguration on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the idea of trying to use separate `<partition/>`s for each container, to try to isolate from one another.

When I tried that, I got the following error:

```
error: internal error: guest failed to start: Failure in libvirt_lxc startup: Failed to create v1 controller cpu for group: No such file or directory
```

And that was actually familiar. I once opened [an invalid bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=886773) because of this.

This error is caused by libvirt not detecting systemd correctly, which is in turn caused by `systemd-container` not being installed. The fix is:

```
apt install systemd-container
```

That fixes both the original issue and my attempt to work around it.